# Error: Required plugin iOS Application is disable

Tags: android, ios, macos, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm starting to develop Kotlin multiplatform Application but whenever i try to run on IOS, it is throwing this error.

System OS : MacOS version - 12.6

[[image: this is screenshot from android studio]]

I've try to fix it by edit configuration but it steel not works. thankyou!